# How to install KDE 4.10 on Precise from repos?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, kde, kde4

I want to install new KDE 4.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Can I install it from any repository and without `kubuntu-desktop` package? I want clean, fresh KDE without Kubuntu modifications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this question from google asking how can I update KDE on (k)Ubuntu 12.04 without updating the server parts of the system.

So, I have Kubuntu 12.04.01 LTE, and there was KDE 4.8.5 installed (along Unity and a few others DMs)

I did

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

.. and now I have same system with KDE 4.10 running on it without much problem so far.

Since the backports are from Kubuntu team, that does include kubuntu-desktop (in your situation it might be a better choice to first install kubuntu-desktop, then update from backports, and then remove extras you don't like too much).

Other option might be looking at http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kde-standard
```

Don't worry about the "kubuntu" in the PPA name. If you install the `kde-standard` package, it won't include Kubuntu's customizations.

Comment: Ok, but I use kde-plasma. ;) Thanks for your answer!